# Seeking a Web Applet Platform For My Gear Ratio Demo

Tags: web-apps, flash

I have a gear ratio demonstration web applet that I made in Mathematica. Unfortunately nobody uses Mathematica's own web plugin so nobody can see my applet. The math is not terribly complicated so there's no reason that I used Mathematica except that it was familiar.

Can someone suggest a more popular tool I could use to remake my applet so that users will actually be able to use it? I'm not actually opposed to learning flash if that is the best tool for the job.